# Identifying a class which is extending an abstract class

Tags: java

Good Evening,

I'm doing a major refactoring of http://wiki2xhtml.sourceforge.net/ to finally get better overview and maintainability. (I started the project when I decided to start programming, so – you get it, right? ;))

At the moment I wonder how to solve the problem I'll describe now:

Every file will be put through several parsers (like one for links, one for tables, one for images, etc.):

```
public class WikiLinks extends WikiTask { ... }
public class WikiTables extends WikiTask { ... }
```

The files will then be parsed about this way:

```
public class WikiFile {
...
public void parse() {
    //Run all parsers on this file.
    if (!parse) return;
    WikiTask task = new WikiLinks();
    do {
        task.parse(this);
    } while ((task = task.nextTask()) != null);
}
}
```

Sometimes I may want to use no parser at all (for files that only need to be copied), or only a chosen one (e.g. for testing purposes). So before running task.parse() I need to check whether this certain parser is actually necessary/desired. (Perhaps via Blacklist or Whitelist.)

What would you suggest for comparing? An ID for each WikiTask (how to do?)? Comparing the task Object itself against a new instance of a WikiTask (overhead)?

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry but I don't really get the idea of your parse function. If you don't want to use a parser, set parse to false? :) 
If I try to guess what you want...I would simply use an enum. Your tasks could hold a `ParserType type;`, so you could do sth. like `if(task.getParserType() == this.getParserType() ) { task.parse(this) }` You surely need to use a List if you want different parsers for a certain task. Regards.

Comment: Yes, not parsing at all already works. Running only certain parsers does not yet. -- Sorry for being unclear, the parse() function I've described above is not part of a WikiTask, but of a File object. Calling parse() on the WikiFile object runs all available parsers as long as there is a next one (I use <code>task.nextTask()</code> because the order matters). -- Using an enum for identifying parsers might really be the easiest way, as they're lightweight too.